# How to show the track route using poly line in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I am developing a bus tracking application where I am getting the location using service from server. Now, with that I want to show the bus movement and draw a proper polyline. I achieved a part of this but facing two main issues:

1. Every time bus marker is showing, it is not getting removed. So, the older footprint of the bus is still present. Although I reached destination, I am seeing many bus icons.
2. I am able to draw the polyline by joining the latitude and longitude but it is showing sometimes a straight line.

I have attached two screenshots for that.
[image]

[image]
The code which I used is here:

```
private void setmMap() {
    progressDialog.show();

    if (broadcastReceiver == null)
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.d("Testing", "inside the setmap");
                 // show progress dialog
                try {
                    double latitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("lat", 22.560214);
                    double longitude = intent.getDoubleExtra("longi", 22.560214);
                    Log.d("SetMap", intent.getExtras().getString("time"));
                    LatLng startLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    m.setPosition(startLocation);
                    points.add(startLocation);

                    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
                    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
                        LatLng point = points.get(i);
                        options.add(point);
                    }
                    line = mMap.addPolyline(options); //add Polyline
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(startLocation));
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(startLocation, 15));
                    progressDialog.cancel();
                    Geocoder geocoder;
                    List<Address> addresses;
                    geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

                    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
                    String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                    String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                    String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
                    String strLoc = "Latitude:: "+latitude+"  ::Longitude::  "+longitude+"  ::Address::  "+address+"  "+city+" "+
                            state;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),strLoc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    progressDialog.cancel();
                }
            }
        };
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("carLocationService"));
}
```

Thanks,
Arindam.

Answer (score 0):

1) you din't show part of code where marker `m` added, possible that code runs several times;

2) seems bus location sensor's polling period is quite large and does not allow tracking bus turns (bus can make several turns between it's known locations). So you need to interpolate path between known bus locations for example with [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro).

Comment: I have modified some part. Now I can see a single map icon. But my requirement is to show a polyline between the start and end point and animate the marker. The location of the marker will get updated each 30 secs. I am getting the latitude and longitude each 30 secs.